# How to disable ReactiveCouchbaseRepository when using PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: java, pagination, couchbase, reactive, spring-data-couchbase

When using SELECT in @Query() although the repository extends PagingAndSortingRepository somehow ReactiveCouchbaseRepository methods are being executed instead of PagingAndSortingRepository methods.
This is my query

`@Query("select * from bucket WHERE field1= $1 AND field2 = $2 AND field3 in $3 AND field4 <= $4")`
The error I am getting is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.ReactiveFindByQueryOperationSupport$ReactiveFindByQuerySupport.lambda$null$1(ReactiveFindByQueryOperationSupport.java:94) ~[spring-data-couchbase-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:432) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.subscribe(EmitterProcessor.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8325) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:188) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:123) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:123) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782) ~[reactor-core-3.3.10.RELEASE.jar:3.3.10.RELEASE]
at com.couchbase.client.core.Reactor$SilentMonoCompletionStage.lambda$subscribe$0(Reactor.java:178) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[na:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.msg.BaseRequest.succeed(BaseRequest.java:143) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.chunk.ChunkedMessageHandler.completeInitialResponse(ChunkedMessageHandler.java:251) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.chunk.ChunkedMessageHandler.handleHttpContent(ChunkedMessageHandler.java:238) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.chunk.ChunkedMessageHandler.channelRead(ChunkedMessageHandler.java:187) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueStreamChannel$KQueueStreamUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueStreamChannel.java:544) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.AbstractKQueueChannel$AbstractKQueueUnsafe.readReady(AbstractKQueueChannel.java:381) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.processReady(KQueueEventLoop.java:211) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.run(KQueueEventLoop.java:289) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[core-io-2.0.9.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

our class definition is

```
public interface MyCouchbaseRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Model, String> {
@Query("SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE field1= $1 AND field2 = $2 AND field3 in $3 AND field4 <= $4"")
List<Model> method(String field1, String field2, JsonArray field3, long field4);
}
```

But when I use

`@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE field1= $1 AND field2 = $2 AND field3 in $3 AND field4 <= $4"")`

its running fine.
I have a use case where I need to use the first query.

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed it seems it's the issue with the couchbase java JPA.
we cannot use `SELECT * FROM bucket` directly we need to include  `SELECT meta().id,_cas,* FROM bucket` then it works fine